# Javascript RegEx and XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, regex, xmlhttprequest, match

I'm about to trying to parse a tag from the text returned by a XMLHttpRequest but I can't get it to work.
I've tested it in w3schools editor (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_regexp_i) where I can it to to work when the text has no newlines but else im stuck:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
req.open('GET', 'www.mysite.com/index.html', false);   

req.onreadystatechange=function() {

   if (req.readyState==4) {
      var text = req.responseText;
      var tag = /<div class='classdef'>(.*?)<div/gm;
      var mt = tag.exec(text);
      alert(mt);
      return;
   }
};

req.send(null);  

</script>
```

At the best the alert box just writes the raw regex "/(.*?)

Anyone got a pointer to what I'm doing wrong? :)

Kind regards.

**UPDATED SOLUTION**

Thx for all your advice, it seems there where more than just one thing amidst in my code. My goal was to feed data into a section of a page from another page. I ended up using jquery as you suggested to achieve this:

```
<div id="IdOfTagToAddTo"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

$('#IdOfTagToAddTo').load('somePageInMyDomain.html #SomeIdOfATag');

</script>
```

I realise that I should have made my initial goal more clear. :S. For that im sorry as I know that always causes confusion :(.
Thx a million for all the pointers you guys gave me. I'm entering the new world (for me at least :)) of jQuery from now on :).

Kind regards

Comment: I'd recommend using any site other than w3schools. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) is good for testing out javascript.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match (and what do you need to not match)? Do you have to deal with nested tags (if so a single regex probably won't do the job)? What do you expect `exec` to return?

Comment: Please refer to accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I think this "answer" is off-topic, so I'll post it as a comment: You're doing a synchronous request (the third parameter to `open` is `false`), but you're using `onreadystatechange`. That will not work reliably cross-browser, and MDC specifically says not to use `onreadystatechange` with synchronous requests. I'd strongly recommend using an *asynchronous* request instead, as synchronous requests lock up the UI of many browsers, making for an unpleasant user experience. So either do that (change the `false` to `true`), or if the request *has* to be synchronous, don't use `onreadystatechange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on gor's anwser.

Using jQuery:

```
  $(req.responseText).find('div.classdef').text()
```

Using split (no regexps), somewhat cryptic:

```
req.responseText.split("<div class='classdef'>")[1].split('</div>')[0]
```

Comment: It took a while as I have never ever done any jquery before but I ended up using load(). I've written the complete solution in my original question and are marking your post as the answer :). Thx for pointing me to jquery, brave new world ahead :).

Answer (score 1):

`exec` method returns array. The first (0 index) is your match, and second (index 1) is match for your group. You should take second element from it.

```
var mt = tag.exec(text);
alert(mt[1]);
```

And add slash to your regex.

But parsing html with regex is veryb **bad** idea. Use something else, jquery for example.

And remember, that you cannot issue XMLHttpRequest to site in other domain.